# How to bind 2 commands from 2 different ViewModels to a Button. WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, command

I need a button to execute two commands from two different ViewModels. I am using communitytoolkit.mvvm

Lets make an example:

INavigator:

```
public enum ViewType
{
    MainView,
    ItemView,
    AddNewItemView
}

public interface INavigator
{
      BaseVM CurrentViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

Navigator:

```
[INotifyPropertyChanged]
public partial class Navigator : INavigator
{
   [ObservableProperty]
   BaseVM currentViewModel = new DashboardVM();

   [ICommand]
   public void UpdateViewModel(object parameter)
   {
       if (parameter is ViewType)
       {
           ViewType viewType = (ViewType)parameter;

           switch (viewType)
           {
               case ViewType.MainView:
                   CurrentViewModel = new MainViewModel();
                   break;
               case ViewType.ItemView:
                   CurrentViewModel = new ItemViewModel();
                   break;
               case ViewType.AddNewItemView:
                   CurrentViewModel = new AddNewItemViewModel();
                   break;
               default:
                   break;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

MainView:

```
xmlns:nav="clr-namespace:........."

   <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Navigator}">

        <Button Command="{Binding UpdateViewModelCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{x:Static nav:ViewType.MainView}"/>

        <Button Command="{Binding UpdateViewModelCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{x:Static nav:ViewType.ItemView}"/>

        <Button Command="{Binding UpdateViewModelCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{x:Static nav:ViewType.AddNewItemView}"/>

   </StackPanel>

  <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Navigator}"
                  Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"/>
```

AddNewItemView:

```
   <.....>
   

        <Button Command="{Binding AddNewItemCommand}"/>       

   <.....>
```

AddNewItemViewModel:

```
[INotifyPropertyChanged]
public partial class ItemViewModel
{
    [ICommand]
    public void AddNewItem()
    {
        //Add new Item
    }
}
```

MainViewModel:

```
[INotifyPropertyChanged]
public partial class MainViewModel
{
     public INavigator Navigator { get; set; } = new Navigator();
}
```

I want to Bind:

Command="{Binding UpdateViewModelCommand}"
CommandParameter="{x:Static nav:ViewType.ItemView}"

To the Button in the AddItemView,
basically I want that Button to execute the "AddNewItemCommand" and then "UpdateViewModelCommand" to go back to ItemView.

Maybe my approach is wrong, or is there an easier way to navigate?

Comment: Why do you declare your view model classes as `partial`? This shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1):

You must improve your view model class design.

Your navigation model is controlled by the *View Model*. This means the general navigation logic takes place in the *View Model*. The *View* only triggers the navigation.
Therefore, the navigation back to a particular view after the current view's *View Model* class has completed its operation, must be executed by the *View Model* too.

Moving the navigation logic to a dedicated type, like your created `INavigator`, to encapsulate the logic and to enable sharing, is the first step.

Next step is to share the **same** instance of `INavigator` between all *View Model* classes that participate in the navigation logic.

You can further improve the design by adding a `INavigator.NavigateToPrevious` method to the `INavigator`.
This way the view model class must not know any particular `ViewType` if its only goal is to navigate back to the previous view model.

To implement such a feature, `INavigator` would have to maintain a navigation history e.g., by using a `Stack<ViewType>` as backing store, to navigate backwards.
To do so, simply push the current `ViewType` of the `CurrentViewModel` to the `Stack<ViewType>` and pop it later in your `NavigateToPrevious` method:

**INavigator.cs**

```cs
interface INavigator
{
  // The set() of this property must be private to add robustness
  BaseVM CurrentViewModel { get; }

  NavigateToViewModelCommand { get; }

  void NavigateTo(ViewType nextViewType);
  bool NavigateToPrevious();
}
```

**Navigator.cs**
Note how the example uses a `Dictionary` that returns a view model factory to avoid the implementation of a type switch.
Also note how using a `Stack<ViewType>` enables a navigation history.

```cs
class Navigator : INavigator
{
  [ObservableProperty]
  BaseVM currentViewModel = new DashboardVM();
  
  private Dictionary<ViewType, Func<INavigator, BaseVM>> ViewModelFactoryMap { get; }
  private Stack<ViewType> ViewHistory { get; }
  private ViewType CurrentViewType { get; set; }

  public Navigator()
  {
    this.ViewHistory = new Stack<ViewType>();
    this.ViewModelFactoryMap = new Dictionary<ViewType, Func<INavigator, BaseVM>>
    {
      { ViewType.ItemView, navigator => new ItemViewModel(navigator) },
      { ViewType.MainView, navigator => new MainViewModel(navigator) },
      { ViewType.AddNewItemView, navigator => new AddNewItemViewModel(navigator) },
    };

    // Load initial view
    NavigateTo(ViewType.MainView);
  }

  public void NavigateTo(ViewType nextViewType)
  {
    if (this.ViewModelFactoryMap.TryGetValue(nextViewType, out Func<INavigator, BaseVM> viewModelFactory))
    {
      // Maintain a navigation history
      this.ViewHistory.Push(this.CurrentViewType);

      this.CurrentViewModel = viewModelFactory.Invoke(this);
      this.CurrentViewType = nextViewType;
    }
  }

  public bool NavigateToPrevious()
  {
    if (this.ViewHistory.TryPop(out Viewtype previousViewType))
    {
      NavigateTo(previousViewType);
      return true;
    }
   
    return false;
  }

  [ICommand]
  public void NavigateToViewModelCommand(object commandParameter)
  {
    if (commandParameter is ViewType viewType)
    {
      NavigateTo(viewtype);
    }
  }
}
```

**AddNewItemViewModel.cs**
Because `AddNewItemViewModel` must know how to navigate, its constructor must accept a shared `INavigator` instance. Follow this pattern for all *View Model* classes that must know how to navigate.
Since `INavigator` exposes a `INavigator.NavigateToPrevious` method, *View Model* classes can navigate to the previous view anonymously:

```cs
class AddNewItemViewModel : BaseVM
{ 
  public ICommand AddNewItemCommand => new DelegateCommand(ExecuteAddNewItemCommand);
  private INavigator Navigator { get; }

  public AddNewItemViewModel(INavigator navigator)
  {
    this.Navigator = navigator;
  }

  private void ExecuteAddNewItemCommand(object commandParameter)
  {
    // TODO::Execute command

    this.Navigator.NavigateToPrevious();
  }
}
```